# What kind of pattern matching does apt-cache allow for specifying package names?

Tags: apt

The question is about `apt-cache` commands other than `search regex`.

I know I can use a star character as a wildcard, for example `apt-cache policy 'firefox*'`, but I could not find any documentation on what else is possible. Is it the same as filename expansion? Does something like `extglob` switch exist for it?

The actual problem i'm trying to solve is to have `apt-cache policy` show me everything `'firefox*'` except all the `-l10n-` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package names are handled as described in the documentation [for `apt-get install`](https://manpages.debian.org/apt-get) (yes, it’s not obvious):

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database. Any matches are then installed (or removed). Note that matching is done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and 'lowest'. If this is undesired, anchor the regular expression with a '^' or '$' character, or create a more specific regular expression.

Strictly speaking, this check comes after a glob performed on the available package names — so package specifications are first checked for an exact match, then checked for glob matches (using `?` and `*`), and if that doesn’t find anything, and the package specification contains `.`, `?`, or `*`, interpreted as regular expressions. (You can see the globbing behaviour by running `apt-cache policy 'firefo?'`, which matches using only a glob, and then `apt-cache policy 'firefox?'`, which ends up using a regular expression.)

`apt-cache policy 'firefox*'` matches using globs. If you want to force it to match using a regular expression, you can use something like `apt-cache policy 'firefox.*'` instead; check for `mozilla-firefox` in the output to see if the expression is matched as a glob or as a regular expression.

`apt-cache search` is documented explicitly as handling regular expressions because its arguments are *always* treated as regular expressions.

Given the kind of regular expressions `apt` supports, excluding `-l10n-` is probably impossible; see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286050/4500798) for details.

Comment: If `pkg` can be interpreted as RE, then why does documentation (`man apt-cache`) distinguish between search (`search regex...`) and all other commands (e.g. `policy [pkg...]`)?

Comment: Regarding `-l10n-`, I do see them as well. I **don't want** to see them. And I'm already single-quoting the name, `'firefox*'`.

Comment: Oh, I had misunderstood, sorry. See my update.

Comment: Would this not be a 100% correct way to exclude packages containing `l10n`: `apt-cache policy 'firefox([^l]|l[^1]|l1[^0]|l10[^n])*$'`?

Comment: No, that also excludes packages ending with `l`, such as `firefox-certificatepatrol`, `firefox-form-history-control`...